# In Android Studio which SDK platform tools to install?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

My SDK Manager shows two platform tools, one which comes under the folder 'Tools' which has revision 22, and the other which comes under the folder 'Tools (Preview Channel)' which has revision 23rc2. When I download and install one, after rebooting the SDK Manager, the other one comes as not installed and vice-versa.

[image]

So if only one can be installed which one should I go for?

Comment: Also I faced this problem, but still didn't get solution

Comment: If i install the one under the general 'Tools' folder, will I still be able to develop for Android M? And if I download the rev 23rc2 one under the preview channel tools, does that hinder my development for other APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only one version of SDK platform tool at a time.
Under tools the Android SDK platform tools means those tools which have been fully developed by Google are are now stable builds.
Under the preview channels are the one which are under development and are in beta stage, they are meant for advanced developers to give them an idea about the new releases and features yet to be offically released.
So, you must go with sdk tools under tools unless you are ready to take in account for those extra features and for some unknown bugs.